# How do I use my own data in this CNN finetune code

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to finetune inception-v3, so that it is able to make a decision between an image with signal present and signal absent. How do I edit the code so that it can train on my data? Here is the code to finetune inception-v3:

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K

# create the base pre-trained model
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', 
include_top=False)

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
# and a logistic layer -- let's say we have 200 classes
predictions = Dense(200, activation='softmax')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# first: train only the top layers (which were randomly 
# initialized)
# i.e. freeze all convolutional InceptionV3 layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile the model (should be done *after* setting layers 
# to non-trainable)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_
crossentropy')

# train the model on the new data for a few epochs
model.fit_generator(...)

# at this point, the top layers are well trained and we can 
# start fine-tuning
# convolutional layers from inception V3. We will freeze the 
# bottom N layers
# and train the remaining top layers.

# let's visualize layer names and layer indices to see how 
# many layers
# we should freeze:
for i, layer in enumerate(base_model.layers):
   print(i, layer.name)

# we chose to train the top 2 inception blocks, i.e. we will 
#freeze
# the first 249 layers and unfreeze the rest:
for layer in model.layers[:249]:
   layer.trainable = False
for layer in model.layers[249:]:
   layer.trainable = True

# we need to recompile the model for these modifications to 
# take effect
# we use SGD with a low learning rate
from keras.optimizers import SGD
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), 
loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# we train our model again (this time fine-tuning the top 2 
#inception blocks
# alongside the top Dense layers
model.fit_generator(...)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you might give.